# Retrieving values from json objects into my template (HTML) using ember

Tags: json, ember.js

This is how i'm fetching a single JSON value inside my template .. 
My application route :

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return {
      url: "myurl"
    };
  }, setupController(controller, model) {
    controller.set("URL", model.url);
  }
});
```

application.hbs :

```
<h1>{{URL}}</h1>
{{outlet}}
```

This works fine. What I want to do now is to fetch the values from this kind of JSON object into my template :

```
{
  "employee": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "name": "Employee1",
    "address": {
      "Street": "25 West Street",
      "city": "City1",
      "state": "State1",
      "Country": "US"
    }
  }]
}
```

- What Code should I be using in my application route to set the
  controller?
- How do i retrieve the value of each and every key in my
  JSON object into my template?
- Is there a way to fetch not only the
  value of the JSON object, but also its key inside my template ? If
  so, how?

Comment: Is model hook return value is hardcoded or will you fetch it from server ?. you can use `each` helper in template to iterate array and you can access javascript properties in template just like accessing it in javascript `employeeObject.address.city`

Comment: Thank you. It will actually be fetched from a server. For now, i'm just hard coding it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not even need to setup the controller. You can directly use what is returned from the `model` hook. Check out the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/f0a97284b32994d71d12ab189ab1d9b8?openFiles=templates.index.hbs%2C). As you can see I returned the data you defined from the `model` hook of `index.js` route and accessed it with `model` from `index.hbs` route template. As kumkanillam suggested in his comment, I iterated over what is returned from `model` hook with `each` helper. I hope this helps.

Comment: @user5739878 if this solves the question you might accept it as an answer; or explain more if you feel you need more direction.

Comment: Well, I want to know the answer for my third question and I also have another problem. The first word of the values which i'm fetching are automatically being capitalized.  employee : "name" is being fetched into the template as Name. How do i get the JSON value as such?

Comment: I am really sorry but your third question does not make any sense to me; please consider asking it in different words; yet again try to give some code snippet of what you mean. Your other question is mostly related with how you return data from your server; may be your json serializer is doing sth. funny. I cannot answer that from what we have in this question. You might consider asking a separate question for that. Do not try to get the whole thing within just question. Sometimes it is better to break down what you have in your hand. Best Regards.

Comment: in a JSON object like this : "myname" : "Abc" ... Instead of fetching "Abc" How do I fetch the key "myname"? That's my third question

Comment: @user5739878 check out the twiddle I provided again. I have written a helper to illustrate you how you can get keys of any json object. You can use the source code within field-extractor helper anywhere you like to get the keys of a json object. Hope this helps.

Comment: @user5739878 by the way why did you unmark the question as unaswered again? I think I have answered your question totally!!!

Comment: I felt your comment was a bit rude to me and one of my questions was still unanswered. It's all clear now. Thanks mate. Accepting it again.

Comment: @user5739878 sorry you felt that way; it was not my intend. we are all here to help each other. hope all of us will succeed on whatever we are deailing with. My best regards.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `setupController` in this instance as anything returned in the model hook of a route is available in the corresponding controller as `model`.

The data could be displayed using the `each` and `each-in` template helpers.

The `each-in` template helper can be used to loop over an object and display the keys and values.

For example, to display the keys and values of the nested `address` property:

```
{{#each model.employee as |employee|}}
  <ul>
    <li>id: {{employee.id}}</li>
    <li>name: {{employee.name}}</li>
    <li>address:
      <ul>
        {{#each-in employee.address as |key value|}}
          <li>{{key}}: {{value}}</li>
        {{/each-in}}
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
{{/each}}
```

[Example on Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c51f33553701ce2cd0c799604268cf80?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C).